# Write a field or class that can be permanently modified (Java, ASM), no database / file

Tags: java, class, artificial-intelligence, java-bytecode-asm, self-modifying

I want to do this:

In my code, a variable X = 1. Compile and run code. The program prompts the user to set X, and X is set to 2 from the user input. The next time I compile and run my code, I want X to be 2, before the prompt.

You could use a file or database to read/write, but the problem is I want to eventually extend the example above beyond field modification, to be able to create a new field or class from user input. I ask about Java (using Eclipse) because I am most familiar with it, although I am having trouble with understanding the ASM integration and how it is used. If anyone has a simple example like mine^^ or can offer guidance, I would appreciate it. To do a simple field modification, are you able with ASM to append the running class file, or would you have to create a new class file (with updated field) and delete the original?

Comment: off topic, but it's generally a good idea to stick with java naming conventions - so make it `x`, not `X`

Comment: A `class` is a file, so what is the difference between writing to a file which has the data you want and a `class` file which has the data you want, (Except writing a class is far, far more complicated)

Comment: Note that even if you patch the bytecodes, you then have the problem of having to switch context to a new classloader if you want to load the patched version... or wait until next time the program loads.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the difference is that I need to write to the file that is currently running

Comment: @keshlam What is involved in switching context to a new classloader? I don't know how 'patching the bytecodes' works

Comment: @user2827214 why, what difference would it make?

Comment: @PeterLawrey you don't see a problem with writing and reading the same object at the same time?

Comment: @user2827214 You can read/write an object in memory at once, you can read/write a file at once.  You can't easily read/write a class which is use however.  It's all do able, but self modifying code is almost certainly going to be the hardest way to do something.

Answer (score 1):

Guidance: Use a library designed to facilitate manipulating Java bytecodes, such as the Bytecode Engineering Library (BCEL). Read the documentation and example programs for that library to understand what tools they give you and how to use them.

Note: you CAN NOT modify code that is already loaded into the classloader and executing environment. Java doesn't allow it. What you can do is generate new code for the class, set up a classloader which understands that for this class it needs to use the new code rather than the one previously loaded, request a new instance of this class from that special classloader, and work with that instance thereafter. Note that any references to previous instances will still be running the old code.

Explaining this in greater detail is beyond the reasonable scope of a StackOverflow post, I think. Again, look at the documentation for bytecode manipulation tools, study their examples, and come back to us with SPECIFIC questions if and when you get hung on something.

Don't expect this to be easy. And with a very few, very specialized exceptions, don't expect it to be practical. Generating new code on the fly is SOMETIMES a reasonable idea, but self-modifying code is ALWAYS a bad idea.

Good luck.

Comment: I had read on other threads that ASM was easier to use initially, including the bytecode plugin for eclipse.

Comment: I think something like BCEL would be easier given your goal of modifying existing classes. But that may be a matter of personal preferences. In any case, the answer is that you're going to have to understand the tool, and the bytecode instruction set, in detail before you can do any of this, and should start by reading the documentation and examples thereof.

Comment: I started that and will continue, but their examples are complex. Just looking for something to bridge the gap.

Comment: There is nothing you can do with bytecode manipulation that will not be complex. You're talking about the equivalent of assembler language and manipulating program structure programmatically. That's unavoidably going to involve painful detail work and deep understanding of the execution model.

Comment: thank you for your responses. My application is for machine learning, despite no training in that area, but I assume it is one of the 'few exceptions' you mentioned where it is actually an OK idea for self-modifying code? Relatively speaking, is the process you described resource intensive (since any time a change was made, a flag would be set and the classloader would request a new instance)?

Comment: Self-modifying code is NOT the right answer here. Modify data structures and use them to drive behavior. Store those values into a file; reload them in the next session.

Comment: I understand what you are saying now. For anyone that sees this post in the future, I am using the method of writing serialized objects to a file, and then reloading those as necessary, instead of modifying class files